# Set OpenVPN client to use the local gateway in while maintaining client-to-client support

Tags: networking, openvpn

I'd like to set up a vpn to allow two separate computers to connect to each other.
I've found [a bunch of places](https://superuser.com/questions/1268056/openvpn-how-to-set-client-to-use-local-gateway-aka-use-connection-for-resourc) where they say you should remove `redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp` from the server config and add a route `route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway` to make connecting to the private network work. But this doesn't seem to do what I want.

Yes it now makes all requests via my local gateway (All servers report my public ip is my own ip, rather than that of the vpn), but now connecting to other clients no longer works.
I can still connect to my own private ip (`10.0.0.0`) as assigned by the vpn, but other clients can not reach me on this same ip.

My client.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn.example.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server

cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256

verb 3
key-direction 1
```

My server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert vpnserver.crt
key vpnserver.key

dh none
topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

client-config-dir ccd

# push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway 1"

client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-crypt ta.key

cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

ccd/myclient

```
ifconfig-push 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
```

How can I make `client-to-client` work without making all my regular traffic flow through the vpn?

edit: After some more experimenting I've figured out that this setup is working fine as long the assigned private ip is in the 10.8.0.x range. I have a few static private ips in the 10.0.0.x range, so that's why it isn't working. I'd still like to use these ips though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the server config to use `10.0.0.x` as default pool.

I changed:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

to

```
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

I don't like that static and dynamic ips are now both using the same pool, but this is the best I can do.